# How to install titlesec and secsty packages?

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)
>   [How can I change the package repository?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository)

Please help me to install packages. When I install the options for random repository package is not shown.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing which TeX distribution you're using.

Comment: There's some pretty explicit answers here: [How do I update my TeX distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/2693).

Comment: Consider updating your distribution from MiKTeX 2.8 to [MiKTeX 2.9](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup).

Comment: The best thing you can do is to *fully* install MiKTeX version 2.9 or TeX Live.

Answer (score 2):

I gather you use MiKTeX 2.8. (Aside: you should really consider updating your MiKTeX distribution to version 2.9!) To manually install packages -- rather than rely on MikTeX's built-in autoloader process -- bring up the "MikTeX Package Manager" program (under "All Programs -> MikTeX -> Maintenance"), search for and highlight (by clicking on) the lines that say "sectsty" and "titlesec", respectively, and click on the "+" (Plus) button. After a few minutes, the packages should be ready for you to work with.

Of course, this method requires you to have a connection to the Internet where your computer is not located behind some firewall. If you *are* behind some firewall, though, you may be out of luck until and unless you can get connected to the Internet differently.