# How can I change the package repository?

Tags: packages, miktex, repositories

The package repository shows that the packages can be installed from internet. But I need it to be installed from random package repository. How can I change it

Please help me

Comment: Please add to your question which distribution you use (texlive, miktex, mactex, ...)

Comment: I use MixTex2.8

Comment: As I couldnt instal packages from random package repository, I clicked on install from internet. But later on I instaled the packages and now I need to change the repository. Please tell me the path which should be browsed to change the repository

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the package manager for that. However, I would recommend you to update to MikTeX 2.9 if possible.

[image]

Then you can go to the Repository Menu and select Change Repository option.

[image]

After clicking next if you wish to have it updated from internet, you would get the list of available repositories.

[image]

Note that, an available repository can be offline temporarily such that you can't download packages or update them.

Comment: Sir.. from the second dialog box i need to select second option and i need the path to b browsed for that.. i don want it to be installed from net because i hav already installed package in my system

Comment: @Vidhya That's also a possibility. You can also use the MikTeX update option to access these menus. Is there any further difficulties that I didn't understand from your comments?

Comment: thank u soooo much......it worked....i have been behind this for a week..really cracked my head

Comment: i used the package to right align the chapter but now the contents, list og figures etc also aligned right..i used \chapterfont{\raggedleft} code...

Comment: @Vidhya You should ask that as a new question with a minimum and compilable code such that others can have a look too.

Comment: In my case it was named `miktex-console.exe`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Miktek version 4.3 (20220313)]

for me worked this way (ssl error 35):

deactivate proxy

try different repos, until you can see the list of packages