# How to change the package repository?

Tags: miktex

I am at work, where we have some security constraints :

- Some websites are blocked
- I have no admin privileges

I have installed MiKTeX portable without any difficulty. I can launch the package manager, but it always fails to connect to the server when trying to install packages.

I'm thinking the repository it's trying to connect to is not allowed by my company. Let's use a mirror.

I have read [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository?newreg=6112fa76dc54461b962edee9b7a7a906) and it's exactly what I want to do.

However, when it tries to load the list of repositories, I get a connection error message.

> MiKTeX Problem Report
>
> Message: Couldn't connect to server
>
> Data:
>
> Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
>
> Line: 334
>
> MiKTeX: 2.9
>
> OS: Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
>
> Invokers: miktex-taskbar-icon
>
> SystemAdmin: no
>
> PowerUser: no

What can I do? Is there a config file where I could set the repository I want to use?

Comment: Can't you completely install the Latex?

Comment: I have downloaded the MiKTeX net installer. Started it and asked to download the full distribution. It asks me to choose a mirror in the list. Loading the list. Could not connect...

Comment: try a repository that uses HTTP, as port 80 ist usually never blocked.

Comment: @Ben This might help, http://www.tug.org/protext/ I had the same issue in my work environment and I used this. This will give you the complete installation. This is also MikTex.

Comment: You could try in the command line of your miktex portable to set a repository with e.g. `mpm --set-repository=http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/` but I have some doubt that it will work. Imho miktex always tries to connect to the main miktex server and if this is blocked it won't work. You could instead use wget or something like this to download the packages from ctan in some folder and use it as local repository.

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work unfortunately. I'm downloading protext, but it 2Gb, so it will be finished during the week-end