# Why is it so difficult to Update MiKTeX in China?

Tags: miktex-update, repositories

```
MiKTeX Package Repositories
https://miktex.org/pkg/repositories
```

[image]
[image]

I can connect to none of these, with or without VPN.

Tried to uninstall and reinstall on fresh Windows 10 systems too.

Never thought I would have a problem installing/using MiKTeX in China!!!!!!

But the fact is, it's been THREE days and I  can only install MiKTeX and couldn't UPDATE anything....

Any solutions???

Reports:

```
Date: 2020-06-10 12:06:41
MiKTeX: 2.9.7400
GitInfo: 8386fcd / 2020-04-21 21:22:55
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 19041
SharedSetup: yes
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: yes
LastUpdateCheckAdmin: not yet
LastUpdateAdmin: not yet
LastUpdateDbAdmin: 2020-06-10 12:03:54
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: yes
AdminMode: yes
Root0: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

The following issues were detected:
  1: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates.
```

Comment: There are mirror sources in mainland China, you can update from there, but I don't know much about this and can't help much.

Comment: You can change to use another MiKTeX package repository (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56788/79060), and choose one located in mainland China.

Comment: This the wrong place to ask. Go to the MiKTeX issue tracker. Bedside this: Can you download MiKTeX packages from a ctan mirror with e.g. wget? If yes you could do this and use it as local repository.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I thought that was loooooooooooooooog ago and now no longer exist?? I mean the "package manager" thing???? It's not in the bunble any more....

Comment: searching the list of MikTeX repo, I'm surprised by the number of mirrors per person in China and in Germany.  The size of the former is that of the Continent, but there're more servers in the later country.  That might explain why it's relatively hard to update the package manager.

Comment: Please take your query to miktex.org.

Answer (score 0):

I am in Taiwan. I have had the same problem before. I then tried installing an earlier version of MiKTeX, e.g., basic-miktex-2.9.7255-x64.exe, and then I could update without problem. Hope this also works for you.

Comment: I tried the latest and the previous one....neither can update.....