# Error when attempting to change (set) package repository (new install)

Tags: errors, packages, compiling, repositories

Thanks to all for making this a great site. This is my first post ever because most questions are already answered here! Although I've used Latex for years, I still consider my technical competency to be low. Please be specific in reply.

My school IT department issued me a new laptop. I asked for MiKTeK (2.9) and TeXnicCenter, which I've always used for writing. When I try to build a file for the first time on the new computer, I run into errors with .sty files not found.

So I followed the instructions to change the repository here: [How can I change the package repository?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56783/how-can-i-change-the-package-repository)

When I select "Packages shall be installed from the Internet" and click "Next" I get an error instead of a list of packages.  I went back to the old laptop, followed the same procedures, and a list of repositories does appear as expected. Image of error and copied info below. Not sure what to do next.

[image: change repository error]

MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Data:

Not Found

### Access Error: 404 -- Not Found

```
Cannot open document for: /Repository.asmx
```

Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
Line: 1564
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Education, 64-bit, build 19044
Invokers: non-existing/explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\tericson\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\tericson\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\tericson\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\tericson\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\tericson\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: well it sounds as if there is a connection problem, which probably only your IT can resolve. To install packages you could try to build a local repository and install from there https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388